# Extraction key frames from a video for scoring a video with some queries

Tags: pattern-matching, computer-vision, object-recognition

I am workin' on a Computer Vision project that we need to score videos according to inclusion of some objects, animals or such defined by queries. But for this mission we firstly aim to retrieve some key frames form the video to process with. Do you know any way to do that extraction? I am very newbie on this subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the method explained there 
https://www.quora.com/Computer-Vision/How-do-we-retrieve-key-frames-from-a-video-for-object-recognition

Comment: Ah, you mean "Scene Change Detection" for video segmentation, rather than simply extracting key frames from the video. Great that you got  an answer - and good luck with this much harder problem!

Comment: P.S. Note that ffmpeg can still help - if you provide an implementation of the filter to use to detect changes, as discussed here: http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Scene-detection-td941845.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using [ffmpeg](http://ffmepg.org)? It is an incredibly powerful utility for all sorts of video manipulation. If you are happy with entering commands directly you can do the following...

Extract a *single* frame (using `-vframes 1`) at a specific time in the video (in this case 12 seconds in), type:

```
ffmpeg -i trial.flv -ss 00:00:12 -vframes 1 -f image2 frame.png
```

Or, to convert an entire video into individual frames - starting at 31 sec and sampling at the frame-rate specified (`-r 5` for 5Hz), type:

```
ffmpeg -i trial.flv -ss 00:00:31 -y -sameq -r 5 -f image2 frame%03d.png
```

The flag `-y` will overwrite existing files and the flag `-sameq` will enforce the same quality per image file. The bit at the end is the name to give the output frames (with 3 zero-padded decimal numbers to distinguish each in order  - `%03d`).

Just make sure you have got enough space to store all those frames!